# Builder C++ calling VC++ class

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2006

I have compiled a Hunspell DLL with VC++ which contains a class...
Now I want to call that DLL in Builder C++ 2006 to use its functions...how I can do that?

I tried with:

```
typedef Hunspell * (CALLBACK *fpoint)(char *aff_file, char *dict_file);
fp pHunspell = (fp)GetProcAddress(handle_Hunspell, "hunspell_initialize");
if (pHunspell) {
  Hunspell* obj = (Hunspell *)pHunspell("..\hunspelldic\en_US.aff", "..\hunspelldic\en_US.dic");
  obj->add_dic("..\hunspelldic\it_IT.aff", "..\hunspelldic\it_IT.dic");
}
```

the matter is if in BuilderC++ 2006 I can show functions after pressing shift-space after obj-> but looks like it doesn't really recognize class functions and it keeps giving out Unresolved external '__fastcall Hunspell::add_dic(...);' referenced from....

What would be the exact way to call a VC++ dll into Builder C++? Thanks in advance to everyone...

Cheers,
Luigino

Answer (score 0):

first you must `#include` a import header file for your **DLL** (including classes, consts defines...)

after that there are 2 ways:

1. **static DLL link**

   is easy but sometimes do not work with **MSVC++ DLLs**. You need Add to project a **LIB** file for your **DLL** which you can create with **implib.exe** in Borland bin folder but you probably must play with command line switches to correct convert used mangling until builder can resolve all externals. for example:

   ```
   implib.exe -c -f -a glut32.lib glut32.dll
   ```

   if you have incorrect lib file then compiler will add your unresolved external errors. Also **obj/lib** files from **MSVC++** are incompatible with Borland/Intel because MS use their nonstandard format. In such case Borland will shout something like **wrong OMF**, hence the **implib** utility
2. **dynamic DLL link**

   in example bellow I link 2 functions from a **DLL**. For linking class you must link all used methods of all classes you import. Also you might have problems with **name mangling in DLL** (similar to static link) so **use some tool to explore dll** (I use DLL Export Viewer ) which shows you the real function names in **DLL** which you must use in `GetProcAddress`. Here an example:

   ```cpp
   HANDLE hdll;
   typedef BOOL(__stdcall *_InitRemoteCtrl)(HWND); _InitRemoteCtrl InitRemoteCtrl;
   typedef DWORD(__stdcall *_ReadRemoteData)();    _ReadRemoteData ReadRemoteData;

   __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
       {
       hdll=LoadLibrary("./RemtCtrl.dll");
       if (hdll==0) Application->Terminate();
       InitRemoteCtrl=(_InitRemoteCtrl)GetProcAddress(hdll,"InitRemoteCtrl");
       ReadRemoteData=(_ReadRemoteData)GetProcAddress(hdll,"ReadRemoteData");
       }

   void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
       {
       FreeLibrary(hdll);
       }
   ```

Use the first option if you can because it is safer. Also do not forget to export/import classes in the **DLL** header file export for **DLL** source and import for **DLL** usage.

```cpp
class __declspec(dllimport/dllexport) myClass
    {
    ...
    };
```

**PS**

While constructing **API** between **MSVC++** and **Borland** be careful what to export/import avoid the use of non standard data types not used in booth platforms (or in the same way like `AnsiString`,...).

Comment: I forgot to mention that winapi function GetProcAddress has some weird bug which in some cases make someof function in DLLs unusable.

Comment: This weird behavior has been tested on w2k sp4,wxp sp1,2,3 x32,w7sp1 x64. In some cases make some of functions in DLLs unlinkable (cannot find desired function nor by name nor by ordinal). This occurs mostly after PE editation (renaming of functions to match old C style mangling).