# how to link cplex callable library (c api ) with c++ builder

Tags: c++builder, cplex

I have IBM's CPLEX 12.7 and Embarcadero's C++Builder.  I am trying to link to CPLEX but I am failing.  So now I want to use the [Callable Library (C API)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/homepageCrefman.html) instead.  My question is, how can I setup C++Builder to call the CPLEX C API? How do I link to it?

Comment: in what form the lib is shipped? *.dll, *.lib, *.obj or something else? for dll you need to create Intel compatible lib import file (with implib.exe from bin directory of BCB) and then add it to project ... for static *.lib and *.obj you can use `#pragma link "path\\blblabla.obj"` and do not forget to include header files. Also beware some libs need to have defined specific configuration `#define`s and or headers included to work/compile/link properly.

Comment: can i ask you to specifie more how to do it

Comment: first specify what kind of lib files you have (file type/extension...)...

Comment: look here [linking MS VC++ DLL into BCB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18030748/2521214)