# Unresolved external when linking C++ Builder dll into MSVC C++ Project

Tags: visual-c++, linker, c++builder

I am trying to use a C++Builder 11.1.5 created DLL in MSVC 2022 C++ project. Both are 32bit. I can't build the DLL in MSVC as it uses some VCL objects.

My C++ Builder defines the external function thus:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SetEnabled(bool val) {
    ...
}
```

MSVC uses a header to reference the function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall SetEnabled(bool val) ;
```

I have created a `.DEF` file with the same name as the DLL, containing this:

```
LIBRARY MYTESTDLL
EXPORTS
 SetEnabled
```

And I have generated a `.LIB` file from this `.DEF` file using MS `lib.exe`:

```
lib.exe /DEF:MYTESTDLL.def /out:MYTESTDLL.lib /MACHINE:x86
```

Finally, I have added `MYTESTDLL.lib` to my MSVC project in the `Linker->Additional Dependencies` section.

But, when I build the program, I get this error:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetEnabled@4 referenced in function _WinMain@16

I've tried adding the ordinal (`@4`) to my `.DEF` file and rebuilding the `.LIB` file, but I still get the same error.

In a hex editor, I can that `__imp__SetEnabled` is in the `.LIB` file, but clearly not in a way that MSVC likes.

Have I missed a step somewhere? Is there anything obviously wrong with what I've done?

Comment: not sure if still true but older C++Builders use different mangling than MSVC++ ... try to use any DLL inspection tool to see the real names inside DLL ... if nothing works use [dynamic DLL function loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18030748/2521214) ...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the MSVC header used to reference the function to:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void SetEnabled(bool val) ;
```

and adjusting the C++Builder DLL to export the functions using `__cdecl` resolved the issue. I didn't realize that the `__stdcall` exported functions need decorating in `.DEF` file.

That said, I find that the DLL is fine unless I try to execute code in it that uses the VCL. Then things don't work properly. I wonder if it's not possible to write a DLL in C++Builder containing VCL code for use in MSVC?

Comment: "dont work properly" - what does this mean? Have you statically linked in all the vcl into your dll ? (project options static link for packages and run time)

Comment: It is not a problem to use `__stdcall` (you should), you just need to make sure the `.DEF` file references the correct exported name. You can use Borland's `TDUMP` or MSVC's `DUMPBIN` tool to get that name from the DLL.